# Increase in self-referrals in Google Analytics since implementation of CDN

Tags: google-analytics, cdn, referrer

Since the implementation of a CDN, my self-referrals have gone from being non-existent to thousands per day, the referral report in analytics with full referrer as a secondary dimension show that the issue is coming from pages sitewide.

Google Tag Assistant recordings indicate that some pages are not sending a hit (GA tag implemented via GTM), most likely when a user clicks off the page quickly.

Has anyone has experienced an increase in self-referrals following the implementation of a CDN?  Or do I need to dig deeper to find another underlying issue?

Comment: CDN's will periodically request and cache your site on nodes throughout their network, so you will get recordings without a hit as you're seeing. It's recommended that you setup [referral exclusions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830).